# Special symbols in Linux

Tags: linux

what is the purpose of $1?  while executing java file, we will give it as command line argument. To which it will refer?

Answer (score 2):

You gave a little context here, but I thinks it's shell argument.

> **ARGUMENTS**
>
> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the `-c` nor the `-s` option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed  to  be the  name  of a file containing shell commands.  If bash is invoked in this fashion, `$0` is set to the name of the file, and the positional parameters are set to the remaining arguments.  Bash reads and executes commands from this file, then exits.  Bash's exit  status  is  the exit  status  of the last command executed in the script.  If no commands are executed, the exit status is 0.  An attempt is first made to open the file in the current directory, and, if no file is found, then the shell searches the directories in `PATH` for the script.

For more detailed, try `man bash`.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$ cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $@
$ ./test.sh hello world
./test.sh
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks,Yes, it is shell argument. So $0 refers first file, $1 refers second file.

Comment: how to execute java class by using from the java installed location?  i mean by using exec command and java file(bin) along with class name?

Comment: @ManiVasu I don't know if I understand you correctly. But the flow is: use javac to compile -> java class name. For example: javac test.java;java Test

Comment: i am trying to execute some class file with some command line arguments in shell script by using exec command. This class specified in some jar file. i added that jar in classpath. But exception thrown "Main class couldnt find". But some other classes in this way, it is working.

Comment: @ManiVasu It's pretty hard to identify the problem here. But there are two issues I can come up with: 1.classpath environment variable is set incorrectly, take additional caution at the seperator(`:` for linux, `;` for win) 2.exec command substitute current process, so the classpath variable need to be exported.

Comment: :Thanks. Actually i specified the location of jar file in one script. I run that scripts and stored the output of that script file in some other variable. I used that variable while executing exec command for java class.

Comment: script. I run that scripts and stored the output of that script file in some other variable. I used that variable while executing exec command for java class. This variable have the location of that jar file in which we specified that class.